# C# - Interface/Class design issue

Tags: c#, oop

I have an interface which is common to Class A, B and C. But now I need to add two methods which is only applicable for Class B and not applicable for classes A & C. So, do I need to add these two methods to the common interface itself and throw not implemented exception in class A & C or is there any better way to do this?

```
interface ICommon
{
   Method1;
   Method2;
   Method3;
   Method4;
}

Class A: ICommon
{
   Method1;
   Method2;
}

Class B: ICommon
{
   Method1;
   Method2;
   Method3;
   Method4;
}

Class C: ICommon
{
   Method1;
   Method2;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why can't you just implement them on class `B` without them being part of the interface? Put another way - why do you want these methods on the interface?

Comment: I second @Oded there may be a mistake in the way you are modelling things.

Comment: Intially we were having only two methods across all classes A, B & C. But now only we have got this requirement which is only applicable for class B. Also, I can implement this only on class B but the client app is referring to the ICommon interface which is created by a factory class.

Comment: If the client app is referring to the ICommon interface and it can't be changed, then yes, you have to include the 2 methods in the interface and raise a NotImplementedException when used with class B. If the client app can be modified, then using 2 interfaces as suggested by @steaks is the best approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If these methods are common to other classes (not just B):

Have B extend another interface

```
interface ICommon2
{
    Method3;
    Method4;
}

class B : ICommon, ICommon2
{
    Method1;
    Method2;
    Method3;
    Method4;
}
```

If these methods are specific to only B:

```
class B : ICommon
{
    Method1;
    Method2;
    Method3;
    Method4;
}
```

Comment: Depending on the circumstances it might also be a good idea to have `ICommon2` inherit from `ICommon`.

Comment: It can be.  But it is not in this case because @user972255 does not want Method3 and Method4 to be in classes A or B

Comment: what @jeremy-todd is saying is that instead of B inheriting from two interfaces, an option is to have the second interface inherit the first so B only would have to inherit from ICommon2. It would still accomplish the same thing as your code. As jeremy said, it depends on what your interfaces and classes represent.

Comment: Ahh, right.  I read it as ICommon : ICommon2...oops!  That makes sense +1.

Comment: @steaks: If I have another interface (ICommon2) then in the client app which is now referring to ICommon interface how we refer to these new methods in ICommon2?

Comment: Not sure if I quite understand what your want...but any class that should implement Method3 and Method4 should extend ICommon2.  If you want the implementations to be exactly the same then you may want a different pattern.

Comment: @steaks: I have a question, now I have created a ICommon2 interface which inherits from ICommon interface but my client app calls a factory class to get the appropriate ICommon interface (instance of class A, B or C). Can you please tell me how to handle class B in the factory class which is now inheriting from ICommon2 interface ?

Comment: Where appropriate, you should cast to ICommon2 or B so you can call Method3/Method4.

Answer (score 1):

If your interface has the methods, you simply MUST implement them, but you can do it secretly:

```
Class A: ICommon
{
   public void Method1() 
   {
   }

   public void Method2() 
   {
   }

   void ICommon.Method3() 
   {
       throw new NotSupportedException();
   }

   void ICommon.Method4() 
   {
       throw new NotSupportedException();
   }
}
```

This is exactly how an array implemments the `IList` interface and hides members like `Add`.

Comment: I don't think @user972255 is required to have Method3 and Method4 on the interface because he asks "do I need to add these two methods to the common interface."  But the explanation of how you can "hide" methods with explicit interface implementation is helpful.  +1

Comment: @Steaks: I know there are different ways to look at this "problem". Since you give a very good answer, I offered this different approach which might not help the OP, but maybe others.

Comment: Completely agree!  That's what I was trying to say in my comment and is why I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If two classes have to implement the same interface but one of the classes needs more methods than the interface contains, those methods do not belong in that interface. Otherwise the other class would also need those methods.

Interfaces describe behaviour, like IDisposable dictates a Dispose() method. If your Method3() and Method4() implement certain behaviour, you should extract an interface from those two methods only and apply that interface to classes that need those methods.